# checkbox bootstrap - how to get the value

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have following html code:

```
<div type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox" name="bootStrap1" class="bootstrap-switch bootstrap-switch-wrapper bootstrap-switch-animate bootstrap-switch-on">
  <div class="bootstrap-switch-container" style="width: 118px; margin-left: 0px;"> 
    <span class="bootstrap-switch-handle-on bootstrap-switch-primary" style="width: 50px;">ON</span>
    <span class="bootstrap-switch-label" style="width: 30px;">&nbsp;</span>
    <span class="bootstrap-switch-handle-off bootstrap-switch-default" style="width: 50px;">OFF</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I get the checked value. I tried follwing but didn't work. Happy for some help.

```
value = $('#myCheckbox').val();
value = document.getElementById('myCheckbox').checked;
```

Comment: A switch isn't a default Bootstrap4 component. I'd suggest finding the documentation and researching there if they offer a JS method to read the selected value.

Comment: @ceejayoz They're not using standard HTML checkboxes.

Comment: @Barmar Then they've mistagged this in various ways, and should consider consulting https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#checkboxes-and-radios to do so.

Comment: @ceejayoz They put "bootstrap" in the title, I added it to the tags for them. And the HTML has `<div>`, the dup you chose is for `<input>`.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. If I use an event listener the checkbox works fine: $("#myCheckbox").on(change, function(event, state) {// do something}. But I can't get it to work by getting the value without switching. I tried:  if ($('#my Checkbox').is(':checked')) { // do somethiung}. But it doesn't work. It always says false.

Answer (score 1):

I don't even know what to say about this:

```
<div type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox" name="bootStrap1" ... >
```

The html code you posted looks to be rendered from [Bootstrap Switch](https://bttstrp.github.io/bootstrap-switch/). If so, then you seem to be missing the `<input .../>` tag.

which would be rendered by a jquery call similar to:

```
$('[name="bootStrap1"]').bootstrapSwitch();
```

Which is looking for HTML similar to:

```
<input id="someUniqueID" type="checkbox" name="bootStrap1" />
```

The jquery call will render html markup that looks similar to the markup in your post, but your rendered code is missing the `<input ... />` tag

Your div may raise an event because you set an event listener, but this jquery, at least to the best of my knowledge (or without a lot of JS), will always fail because div's cannot be checked:

```
//  always fails because #myCheckbox is a div
$('#myCheckbox').is(':checked');
```

Try this instead:

```
$('#myCheckbox input[type=checkbox][name="bootStrap1"][checked]')
```

This jquery looks inside the div for a checked `input[type=checkbox][name="bootStrap1"]`.  But will fail if there is no html input tag in the markup.